# How to svn export with automatically creating the relative directory/path?

Tags: svn

Normally I do this manually:

1. `mkdir -p folder1/foder2/folder3`
2. `cd folder1/foder2/folder3`
3. `svn export svn://127.0.0.1/svn/app1/branches/branch1/folder1/foder2/folder3/file1.txt`

Is there a way or straight svn export command that I don't need to do step 1 and 2? I'm hoping there's a easier way that svn will automatically create the directory structure from SVN to my local machine.

Thanks!

Comment: I being a PHP person, would say that you could use Phing to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now I came up with a bash script that creates the relative path. 
I have no depth knowledge of bash scripting, so this is kinda ugly. Please forgive me. 
But hopefully, this stirs an idea.

**svn_export.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
for var in "$@"
do
    svnArg1=$var;
    svnArg2=`echo "$svnArg1" | sed -e 's/file:\/\/\/usr\/share\/svn\///'`;

    tempDir=`dirname $svnArg2`;
    tempFile=`basename $svnArg2`;
    if [ -n "$tempFile" ]; then

        if [ ! -d "$tempDir" ]; then
            echo "mkdir -p $tempDir";
            echo `mkdir -p $tempDir`;
        fi    

        echo "svn export $svnArg1 $svnArg2";
        echo `svn export $svnArg1 $svnArg2`;

    fi

done

exit 0;
```

**Usage:**

`sudo svn diff -r 1:HEAD --summarize file:///usr/share/svn/TestRepository/ | awk '{print $2}' | xargs ./svn_export.sh`

**Output**

```
A TestRepository/trunk/test2.txt Export complete.
A TestRepository/trunk/test3.txt Export complete.
A TestRepository/trunk/test.txt Export complete.
```

So basically, you only just need to modify this string `file:\/\/\/usr\/share\/svn\/` in the `sed`'s argument to whatever is your svn URL.

Example: `svn:\/\/127.0.0.1\/svn\/project1\/branches\/`

So now, the usage will be like:

```
svn diff -r 1540:HEAD --summarize svn://172.0.0.1/svn/project1/branches/branch1 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs ./svn_export.sh
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If case of **known hard-coded path** in repository - yes, just write destination path in export (by hand)

`svn export svn://127.0.0.1/svn/app1/branches/branch1/folder1/foder2/folder3/file1.txt folder1/foder2/folder3/file1.txt`

In case of dynamically changeable relative path - no, you have not internal pre-made options. But if you export content of revision from repository, you can implement it with `svnlook` subcommands and own logic in code

Comment: Thanks! This will only work for few files but I need something that exports all committed files to a branch which can be alot and from different paths.

Comment: @spock - ok, give **detailed** description of **business-task**: "all commited" is just export of tree from tree-root, "all committed in revision range" is another export, export from Working Copy is third, export from from server with repository on local FS - fourth. All all use different tricks

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a `-p` equivalent in `svn export/checkout` as in `mkdir`, your best bet is to make a function in your `.bashrc`

```bash
function svnExport() {
    mkdir -p "$(dirname "$1")" && svn export "$0$1" "$1"
}
```

So your specific example would be

```bash
svnExport 'svn://127.0.0.1/svn/app1/branches/branch1/' 'folder1/foder2/folder3/file1.txt'
```

---

EDIT: Turns out `--force` will handle subdirectories, but has side-effects like automatic overwriting. So if you're not concerned about that then you could just do

```bash
svn export --force 'svn://127.0.0.1/svn/app1/branches/branch1/folder1/foder2/folder3/file1.txt' 'folder1/foder2/folder3/file1.txt'
```

or

```bash
function svnExport() {
    svn export --force "$0$1" "$1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing this with SVN UI and that worked fine.

Lets say I have a folder 'abc'. I want to export in folder 'build' (which doesn't exists) a file .

[image: Image showing source url and destination directory]

This export the file successfully after creating the build folder. As for command line options, I tried all possible ways. It doesn't create a new folder itself. The folder needs to exist already.